# Visual Studio Set Up Project (or Wix) and Add Host Entry

Tags: visual-studio, wix, setup-project

I want to add a host entry inside C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. Is it possible with Visual Studio Set Up Project?

I have also tried with Wix with the following but not working?

```
    <CustomAction Id='ExecAddHostEntry' 
Directory="INSTALLDIR" 
Execute="deferred" 
ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k "@echo off &amp; SET NEWLINE=^&amp; echo. &amp; FIND /C /I """a.com""" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ^&amp; ^ IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ^&amp; ^ ECHO %NEWLINE%^   127.0.0.1   a.com>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ^&amp; ^ exit"' Return="check" Impersonate="no">
</CustomAction>
```

Update: `cmd.exe /Q /C "find /I """a.com""" aa > nul || echo/& echo   127.0.0.1   a.com>>aa"` command helped me

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cc982255(v=vs.85)

Comment: Have you tried to run Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: How does [this sample code look?](https://github.com/Xynratron/IisManagement/blob/9dd6fa410ad36445489077b0b6fbb2a26bad6a9e/IisManagement.Server/ServerHostsFile.cs).